# How to open certain file types with Visual Studio's Binary Editor by default?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2013

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Professional, which has this great tool called "Binary Editor". I've been using it for a while, through File>Open menu, but I'd like to configure Windows to use it when opening certain file types (with double-click). I tried opening .bin files (which are simple exe files with renamed extension) with C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe, but I get the message "The program you have selected cannot be associated with this file type".

What can I do about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a registry key that stops you from doing this the wrong way.  Fire up Regedit.exe, you can see the key at HKCR\Applications\devenv.exe.  The NoOpenWith value generates this error message.

A starting point to get this correct is to look how it is done for other files.  Say `HKCR\.cs`, note how it points to `VisualStudio.cs.12.0`.  Which contains the relevant keys, I think that the monkeying with DDE is important.